# Get Shopify categories collection for a specific store via API in Shopify App - OhMyBrew App

Tags: php, laravel, api, shopify, shopify-app

I have multiple stores in my **Shopify Account**. I am trying to get all custom categories collection.

I have developed an App by extending Laravel's **OhMyBrew** package, which is installed on all stores, but that app is returning only last store's categories collection.

I want that app to return categories by its store specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think This Package will allow you to query only logged-In Shop's data via API.And you wanted to access store's data regardless session. Might be in back-end CRONS.

use below function to achieve this.

```
 function getShopApi( $shop_id ){
      $shop = \OhMyBrew\ShopifyApp\Models\Shop::where([
                ['id' , '=', $shop_id]
            ])->first();
            $shop = $shop->toArray();
            $api = new \OhMyBrew\BasicShopifyAPI();
            $api->setShop($shop['shopify_domain']);
            $api->setAccessToken($shop['shopify_token']);

            return $api;
    }

    $api = getShopApi( 1 );
    $collections = $api->rest('GET', '/admin/collections.json');
```

Comment: Upvoted (Y) its working but I need something more perfect. I don't have shop id

Comment: When store logged-in to your APP you will get shop_id it in the session. and if you want to run this function in the CRON. you can fetch it from database. ( Might be Shop model and shops table will work here ).

if you are running cron for all stored then code will be something like this [CODE_START]

foreach(Shop::all() as $shop) { getShopApi($shop->id); // } [CODE_END ]

to use function directly as I did you have to create it in the Helper function. but I would suggest you to create this function in Shop Model.